# Firebase Functions - Error: There was an error deploying functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

For some reason, I don't know, my cloud function isn't working with the error being:

```
!  functions: failed to update function projects/jungschar-website/locations/us-central1/functions/createUser
Failed to update function projects/jungschar-website/locations/us-central1/functions/createUser

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        createUser(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

index.ts

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

export const createUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  db.doc("users/" + user.uid).set({
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    isAdmin: false,
  });
});
```

firebase-debug.log
https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/827e6ed903df4ad097e6551bd859884f

Please help me. I've been googling for so long

Answer (score 1):

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

// const db = admin.firestore();
export const createUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  admin.firestore().doc("users/" + user.uid).set({
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    isAdmin: false,
  });
});
```

This works